# Why does Android Studio don't recognize .jar library imports?

Tags: android, jar, android-studio

I'm trying to use some .jar files as libraries in my Android Studio project.

I've been looking on how to do it, and the regular way is to copy the .jar file in the libs folder, and then add it as library. I know the libs folder must be inside "app" module in the "project" view. But that option to add as library doesn't appear. So my approach is to add it manually doing right click on "app" and:

Open Module Setings/app/Dependencies/ and there add .jar files as **file dependency.**

Then, I go to my .class but the import suggestions don't let me select these libraries as import.

I have tried another approach from the "android" view. Doing right click on "app" and selecting "new module", there I select **Import .JAR or .AAR Package** and then I do the same as before from Open Module Setings, but this time I add it as **Module Dependency.**

In booth ways, the gradle.build file is updated adding these dependencies, but when going to the activity to select the import, it doesn't give me the chance to select the import from these ones.

I have spent a full day trying to solve this, but I don't get my activity to recognize the imports from these files, so I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing to do.

Top-level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

app-level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/values-v14'] } }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':activation')
    compile project(':mail')
}
```

Comment: where is your `build.gradle` ?

Comment: If you added .jars in your `libs` then it'll automatically recognized by   `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: @M D I know that it should be that way, but for some reason when I try to import a class and it lets me choose between multiple choices, the one that should be from the jar file doesn't appear.

Comment: You mean from `Project Structure --> Dependency`.

Comment: Or another way is directly add   `compile files('libs/YourFile.jar')`  in `build.gradle` in `dependencies`  and then `Sync Gradle`

Comment: @M D Yes I mean the one from the dependecy. I have also tried to get these libraries from Maven Central Search, and I found them there. I tried to use them in my projects and tha activity recognized the imports. But when executing the app, it was throwing some kind of errors realted to some clases of the library, and some people has suggested me to use the jar files instead this, because that error was realted to something missing

Comment: @M D I have also tried to do it that way...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75269/discussion-between-m-d-and-masmic).

Answer (score -6, accepted):

After a chat with M D we arrived to the conclusion that my AS does not recognize the .jar files, so I have had to port the project back to eclipse, and it works fine there.

Comment: Android Studio definitely recognizes jar files. If it's not working, there's gotta be some other issue.

Comment: @Shivama Verma, for shure, other way lots of people will be reporting that issue. Anyway, in my case, I've tried lots of things and no one works. So maybe my AS version has a bug or something else and that is causing AS not to recognize .jar files.

Comment: @masmic Which version of AS do you use? I had the same problem with 1.5.1. I'm trying to use ksoap2 library, and it gives "Cannot resolve symbol request" in the line SoapObject.request

Answer (score 31):

My current project using gson-2-2.4.jar and YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar and some others. To import those jar, I put it in my libs folder. After that, go to build.gradle and delete some characters in it, and rewrite (1). Finally, click "sync now" (2). I don't know why my sync button [image] does not work when I add jar to libs, so I do that, and it work so well.

[image]

**UPDATE**

On Android 3.x.y we can use `Sync Project with Gradle Files` or `Refresh all Gradle projects`

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I've been playing lot with build.gradle file. I get to sync manually every time I add a .jar in libs, but even doing that, the activity didn't recognize the imports.

Comment: :( oh, I do not have another answer for your question. Sorry about that.

Comment: It blows my mind why this works and clicking on "Sync Project With Gradle File" doesn't work.

Answer (score 18):

[image]
Firstly, I import this JAR, AS can not recognize this JAR and I can not import.
And than I press right click in this JAR and choose "Add as Library". AS can recognize this JAR and solve the problem!!

Answer (score 5):

With Respect to Android Studio 1.5.1:

You need to copy and paste the JAR file into:

APP_NAME/app/libs

Note that the libs folder will already exist. Once copied, change the project view from Android to Project files.

Open up the app/libs folder and right click the JAR file, then click Add As Library.

That should do it. I wasn't able successfully use the Add Module to import a JAR file.

Comment: Atcually it's even easier.  Go to File - New - New Module, and select "Import JAR/.AAR Package" from the pictures.